# My Github profile and contributions aren't visible to others

Tags: github

On January 27 I got mail from GitHub saying that I need to change my password. so did changed my password now my account isn't visible to other.
Then I opened a GitHub Support ticket to resolve the issue, its day 7 and no response from them.
Anyone can help me with this how to get response from GitHub support.

[**My GitHub Link**](https://github.com/19sajib)

It's really frustrating I can't send my resume to recruiter while I am looking for job.

Comment: Can you view your own github account? If so, your profile may be set to private: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/setting-your-profile-to-private

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner yes i can view my own profile, i have check that my profile isn't private mode also i can't connect it with any third-party app like vscode.